# Asp.net Login Status page

Tags: asp.net

How can I use session variable to display user information after authenticated login like Address: 37, kings Road. Position: Secretary base on User ID

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically display data on a page depending on whether or not the user is authenticated, ASP.NET has the built-in [LoginView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx). This has two templates (or more if you're using roles) that can display differing information e.g.

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server" id="LoginView">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        You are not logged in.
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Address: <% =Session["address"] %><br />
        Position: <% =Session["position"] %>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

It's a little difficult to say for definite whether or not you should be storing address/position in Session state without knowing a little more about how you're doing user management e.g. whether you're using an ASP.NET membership provider or you've rolled your own, but bear in mind that if you're explcitly managing putting that information into Session state, you need to make sure that if the user then updates that information you update what's held in Session.

Answer (score 0):

After succesful login save the data you want on session

```
Session["Address"] = "37 Kings road";
Session["Position"] = "Secretary";
```

And retrieve later where you need it

```
string address = Session["Address"];
string position = Session["Position"];
```